# animate.css - How to change the amount of position shift (e.g. in fadeInUp)?

Tags: css, animation, animate.css

I installed animate.css and am quite happy with it. Only one thing I cannot change: the amount of the position change.

In particular I use the animation "fadeInUp" and want to change from what point exactly the fading starts. At the moment it's too much.

I checked the css file but the only thing I found concerning this is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}

.fadeInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

I can't see how I can change that here. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it's the `translate3d` so you need to learn more about how it works

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint. I expected something like top, bottom, margin ... In fact changing the translate3d amount from 100% to 10% fixed the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!